# My update modal is not showing, what is the problem with my code?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

This is my code to display the table and fetch the data from the database. When I click the Edit button, the modal is not showing, what is wrong with my code? Please help me. The first set of code is the index.php file and second is the update-product.php file which is the file for modal.

```
<?php

                                        require_once "config.php";
                                        //$i = 1;
                                        $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `product_stock`") or die(mysqli_error());

                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                                    ?>

                                    
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row" class="text-center"><?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?></th>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["price"]; ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["category"]; ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["supplier_name"]; ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["qty_stock"]; ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><img src="images/<?php echo $row["product_img"]; ?>" width = 200 title="<?php echo $row['product_img']; ?>"></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" type="button" data-target="#update_modal<?php echo $row["product_id"]?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    

                                    <?php
 
                                        include "update-product.php";
                                    }
                                
                                    ?>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="update_modal<?php echo $row["product_id"]?>" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form method="POST" action="do-update-product.php">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Update Product</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Product ID</label>
              <input type="text" name="prodid" value="<?php echo $row["product_id"]?>" class="form-control" required="required"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Product Name</label>
              <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="<?php echo $row["product_id"]?>"/>
              <input type="text" name="prodname" value="<?php echo $row["product_name"]?>" class="form-control" required="required"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Lastname</label>
              <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]?>" class="form-control" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Address</label>
              <input type="text" name="qty_stock" value="<?php echo $row["qty_stock"]?>" class="form-control" required="required"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button name="update" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: i am using bootstrap 5

Comment: i solved it. i found a same problem and i didn't realize that the data-target and data-toggle is now data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle. thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you use Bootstrap 4

```
<button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" type="button" data-target="#update_modal<?php echo $row["product_id"]?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button>
```

if you use Bootstrap 5

```
<button class="btn btn-info" data-bs-toggle="modal" type="button" data-bs-target="#update_modal<?php echo $row["product_id"]?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button>
```